# Change a shortcut's target from command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, shortcut

I'm normally a Linux guy, but I need to write a batch script on Windows to change the target of some shortcuts. Is there a command to do that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I doubt there is a way to do it with a batch script. It's [doable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xk6kst2k(VS.85).aspx) in VBScript, though.

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set shortcut = sh.CreateShortcut("C:\Wherever\Shortcut.lnk")
shortcut.TargetPath = "C:\Wherever\Whatever.txt"
shortcut.Save
```

Save the script in a file ending in vbs and run it from the command line using `cscript whatever.vbs`.

(Don't be fooled by the name -- `CreateShortcut` is used to both create and modify shortcuts.)

Comment: and he can call a vbscript file from his batch file with cscript

Comment: Excellent. This would be perfect. I'll still write a batch script, because I don't want to learn VB, but use your VB script. Thanks Tmdean and Kenny!

Comment: Is there a way to force the target -- regardless of whether you actually have permissions to access the target yourself? I'm trying to make a shortcut that points to the new location for the contents of a folder, but Windows won't let me set the target since I don't have permissions on the target. I don't need access to the target myself, I just want to be able to point others to it who may have those permissions.

Answer (score 7):

There isn't a native program that comes with windows to achieve this.  I scoured the internet for this same functionality awhile ago and stumbled upon the free software [XXMKLINK](http://www.xxcopy.com/xxcopy38.htm).

> With XXMKLINK, you can write a batch
>   file for software
>       installation which has been done by specialized instllation
>       programs.  Basically, XXMKLINK is to gather the  information
>       from a command line and package it into a shortcut.
>
> Command syntax of XXMKLINK:
>
> ```
> xxmklink spath opath [ arg [ wdir [ desc [ mode [ icon[:n] ]]]]]
>
> where 
>
>   spath     path of the shortcut (.lnk added as needed)
>   opath     path of the object represented by the shortcut
>   arg       argument string (use quotes with space, see below)
>   wdir      path of the working directory (for "Start in")
>   desc      description string (shown in Shosrtcut's Properties)
>   mode      display mode (1:Normal [default], 3:Maximized, 7:Minimized)
>   icon[:n]  icon file [with optional icon index value n]
>
>   In addition to the above, the following switches are supported
>   which can be placed in any position in the command line.
>
>   /p        prompts before action
>   /q        no output when successful (quiet)
>   /e        checks error condition strictly
> ```

The downside is you'll need to copy the xxmklink exe onto each computer with the batch script.

A link to download it is available at the bottom of the linked page.